# Catch the method arguments in test

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart, mocking

In my test, InjectedClass is mocked, as it is accessing external resources (see code below).
I'm trying to catch arguments passed into `injected.method2`.
I'm using [mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito), but I cannot seem to find anything that I can use. There is "Then" mocks and "verify" tests, these I cannot use.

Is there any method to catch the incoming argument in a mocked call?

```
class RealClass() {
    InjectedClass injected;

    RealClass(this.injected);

    void method1(argument) {      
      var newArgument  = change(argument);
      injected.method2(newArgument);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "catch arguments"?  Could you provide a specific example of what you want to accomplish?  You can make a `Mock` return or throw in response to specific arguments, but if you want to do anything beyond that, you'll probably want to use a `Fake` instead.

Comment: Yes, I think using Fake is solution.